# How to force Keil to compile with software float for STM32?

Tags: stm32, floating-point

When I am trying to create a float variable in Keil to program STM32 it just crashes.

I had a look online and as far as I read it tries to use hardware floating point unit (which is not enabled and I don't want to use it).

If I want to use software based floatin point then I have to specify that in my compiler.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Keil Compiler Options (ALT+F7 - Target tab) you can select Floating Point Hardware - Not used. That should solve the problem.